# Mongoose.connect is not a function after exports from other files

Tags: node.js, mongodb, vue.js, mongoose

I was trying to read data from mongodb use mongoose in Vue, but the console return err 'mongoose.connect is not a function'. I wonder why this is happen? I try to run the server file(mainDashStatus.js) alone, and it works just as expected. helps?

db.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/dev6'

connect = () =>{
    mongoose.connect(url, { useNewUrlParser: true }).then(console.log('Database Connected')).catch(err => {console.log(err)})
}

disconnect = () =>{
    mongoose.disconnect().then(console.log('Database Disconnected')).catch(err=>{console.log(err)});
}

exports.connect = connect;
exports.disconnect = disconnect;
```

mainDashStatus.js

```
const Config = require('../model/config');
const dbConnect = require('./db').connect;

dbConnect();

checkStatus = (callback) =>{
    Config.find({parentid:null}).exec((err, docs)=>{
        callback(err, docs)
    })
}

checkStatus((err, docs)=>{
    status = true;
    docs.forEach(element => {
        if(element.latesStatus != 'success') status = false
    });
    console.log(status);
    module.exports = status;
})
```

main script

```
<script lang="ts">
import { Component, Prop, Vue } from 'vue-property-decorator';
const checkMainDashStatus = require('../server/mainDashStatus');
export default {
  data(){
    return{
       ....
    }
  },
  methods:{
    status(){
        if(checkMainDashStatus){
          return "background-color: #00FF00;" // green
        }
         return "background-color: #FFFF00;"// yellow
        },
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: This is because Mongoose runs on the server, while Vue.js runs on the client (browser). You cannot use the MongoDB connector inside the browser since it depends on Node.js specific APIs and OS access. You can communicate with your server via HTTP requests or WebSockets.

Comment: that make the question clearer, thanks@TsvetanGanev

Answer (score 0):

You're using a `.then(...).catch(...)` function with mongoose which it doesn't support by default. The safe way to use Promises with mongoose is by passing a global Promise.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/dev6'

mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;

connect = () =>{
    mongoose.connect(url, { useNewUrlParser: true }).then(console.log('Database Connected')).catch(err => {console.log(err)});
}
...
...
```

I hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem.  Was using

```
let mongoose = require("mongoose");
```

As soon as I switched to

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
```

problem solved.